# Retrieving a File from a Virtual Folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a rather simple task, retrieving an image file from a virtual folder outside of my ASP.Net web Application (The Virtual Folder is in the root of the website) and then displaying it in an image control. I am able to to access a Virtual Folder that is within the web site. Here is my code that

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sourcefile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Common/Images/LAPDPatch.jpg")
    Image1.ImageUrl = sourcefile
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ok, I was able to figure it out:

## Solution

Ok, I was able to get it working, I was using the wrong "slash" character I was using the forward slash instead of the back slash:

```
Dim sourcefile As String = Server.MapPath("\VitualFolderName\") & "Images\LAPDPatch.jpg"
```

Thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use`ResolveUrl`:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'root of currently running app, virtual or not
    Dim sourcefile As String = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Common/Images/LAPDPatch.jpg")

    'root of site
    'Dim sourcefile As String = "/Common/Images/LAPDPatch.jpg"

    'root of another site
    'Dim sourcefile As String = "/VirtualDir/Common/Images/LAPDPatch.jpg"

    Image1.ImageUrl = sourcefile
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the url that your code is producing "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite\VirtualFolderName\Images\LAPDPatch.jpg"

Comment: Rick Thanks again, the above code works fine if the Virtual Folder is a sub-folder in the website. What I want to do is to access a virtual folder that is located in the root of the IIS Server.

Comment: What are the paths of each and I can help you?

Comment: IIS Root --> VirtualDir and IIS Root --> MyWebSite. Thanks for sticking with this.

Comment: I was using the wrong slash, see my OP for more information, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user that the web application is running as (maybe "iis appPool\default appPool" under iis7) has access to that folder, it might just be an ntfs permissions thing.